# How to debug a dockerized Golang app with Goland IDE and Docker compose

Tags: docker, debugging, go, docker-compose, goland

I am coding an dockerized Golang app with IDE Goland and Docker Compose because my code depends on several services.

I have found on internet [posts like this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2018/04/30/debugging-containerized-go-applications/) that describe how to debug a Dockerized Golang app but I don't know how to do it when I launch my containers with docker-compose

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

Ways like configuring *Dockerfile* file like in post you linked are not working for me. It's very hard to make *Delve* working well and make **GoLand** to listen it.

There is easiest way to configure **debug** on **Docker** from **GoLand**:

- Select **Run > Manage targets**
- Add new target by pressing **+** button
- Select **Docker**
- Name it as you wish
- Select your **Docker server**
- Select **Image: Pull**
- Enter **Image tag:** name to run on (I will use latest ***golang:1.16.6***)
- Edit **Run options:** add something like port exposing or anything else that you provide for `docker run` command: *"--rm -p 8080:8080"*
- Other fields will fill automatically if you already has image downloaded

---

Now add configuration to run on this container:

- Select **Run > Edit configurations**
- Add configuration **Go Build**
- Select **Run on:** recently created target
- Select **Build on remote target** if you want to build your app in container

Done. You can run and debug with this configuration.

Example:
[image: Example target settings]

[image: Example configuration settings]

To create dockerfile for deployment with similar environment you can use this preset:

```
FROM golang:1.16.6 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o yourApp

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /app/yourApp /
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "/yourApp " ]
```

Comment: Is this related to docker compose? As I understand its a GoLand build configuration which does not include any docker compose configuration so the running build does not have any connectivity to other docker containers e.g. a databse. Is this correct?

Comment: @fabs When you creating configuration just select _Docker-compose_ instead of _Docker build_ and pass compose file path